# Access localStorage after being deleted from global scope

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is there any way to access the localStorage after the `localStorage` property have been removed from the global scope, or is it effectively unaccessible from any script that runs afterwards that doesn't have a reference to it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can be fairly trivially retrieved like so (it won't work inside of the demo as localStorage is sandboxed here, but in the console it will work):

```js
  window.localStorage.setItem('test', 'it works')
  delete window.localStorage
  var x = window.open("","","")
  window.localStorage = x.window.localStorage
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'));
```

Comment: I can also `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')).contentWindow.localStorage`! ty